# Converter de decimal ou inteiro para horas em php

Tags: php

Tenho o resultado em decimal ou inteiro das horas:

> ```
> Utilizador 1 = 71.5 horas
> Utilizador 2 = 137 horas
> ```

Queria converter dentro do php para horas, como exemplo:

> ```
> Utilizador 1 = 71:30
> Utilizador 2 = 137:00
> ```

Estou a utilizar este código no `while` para chegar às horas em decimal ou inteiro:

```
$Total = 0;
while ($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
  $teste = $rows_cursos['Horas Consumidas'];
  $tempo = explode(":", $teste);
  $tempototal = $tempo[0]*60 + $tempo[1];
  $Total = $Total + $tempototal; 
}
$Total = $Total/60;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma simples:

```
function convertHoras($horasInteiras) {

    // Define o formato de saida
    $formato = '%02d:%02d';
    // Converte para minutos
    $minutos = $horasInteiras * 60;

    // Converte para o formato hora
    $horas = floor($minutos / 60);
    $minutos = ($minutos % 60);

    // Retorna o valor
    return sprintf($formato, $horas, $minutos);
}
```

Em seu código:

```
$Utilizador1 = 0.5;
$Utilizador2 = 137;

echo 'Utilizador 1: ' . $Utilizador1 = convertHoras($Utilizador1) . ' horas';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Utilizador 2: ' . $Utilizador2 = convertHoras($Utilizador2) . ' horas';
```

Resultado:

```
Utilizador 1: 00:30 horas
Utilizador 2: 137:00 horas
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Gwa1Xn)

Comment: Se `$minutos` é menor que 60, `$horas` sempre será 0, então aquela operação, `floor($minutos / 60)`, seria desnecessária.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss verdade cara !

Comment: Mas como aplico com o código que tenho essa função?

Comment: @Iniciante Acabei de postar

Comment: Poderia até fazer um `if` para o cálculo de horas caso os minutos forem menores que 60, mas eu não vejo necessidade, pois se irá chegar condição e execução (no caso maior) seriam 2 passos contra 1, e caso minutos forem menor, será um passo de verificação ou já o `floor`direto.

Comment: Coloquei assim, mas não funciona: `$tabela4 .= '<strong>Total de Horas Consumidas:</strong> ' . $Horas = convertHoras($Horas) . ' horas';`

Comment: Você está declarando a variável `$Horas` dessa forma. O correto é `' . echo convertHoras($Horas) . '`

Answer (score 0):

Uso essa function:

```
function converterParaHora($dec)
{
    $seg = ($dec * 3600);
    $hor = floor($dec);
    $seg -= $hor * 3600;
    $min = floor($seg / 60);
    $seg -= $min * 60;
    return lz($hor).":".lz($min).":".lz($seg);
}
```

A ideia veio daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102680/how-to-convert-a-decimal-into-time-eg-hhmmss